# Multiple effects Fancybox V2

Tags: jquery, fancybox, fancybox-2

I am trying to add multiple effects in Fancybox V2 and find that the first effect overrides the second. They work alone but not together. How do I add multiple effects to one image gallery?  Here is how I am trying to combine them:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $('.fancybox').fancybox();

        // Change background color

        $(".fancybox").fancybox({
helpers : {
    overlay : {
        css : {
            'background' : 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.10)'
         }
    }
}
});

        // Remove white border around content

   $(".fancybox")
     .attr('rel', 'gallery')
     .fancybox({
      padding : 0
      });               

        });
</script>
```

Comment: What if you move `padding:0` to the earlier fancybox and delete the last one?

Comment: you can use the same selector for different type of content or for a gallery and individual elements at the same time, but you need to be more specific what effects for what type of content. Show how your html looks like

Comment: Here is my html, I am just trying to modify the Fancybox index page for now.

Comment: I put it in a jsfiddle (my first so hopefully correct). The weird thing is that it works in the fiddle with no dark background and no boarder around pic but when I upload it to my hosting account it does not work. http://jsfiddle.net/dtme/x6t28/

Comment: Here is a new jsfiddle with the three effects I am attempting. http://jsfiddle.net/dtme/cm5b6/

Comment: You said you want different effects so the question is : when do you want each one of them? or on what elements you want each effect?

Comment: Sorry if I was not clear. I want to remove the white boarder around content, have the background overlay be transparent and have the navigation arrows visible on the outside of the box.

Comment: I also want all of the effects at the same time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
I want to remove the white boarder around content, 
have the background overlay be transparent and 
have the navigation arrows visible on the outside 
of the box all of the effects at the same time
```

Then you only need a single script (no need to add a new one for each effect) AND a bit of css to place the arrows outside of the box so

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".fancybox").fancybox({
        padding: 0, // remove the white boarder around content
        margin: [20, 60, 20, 60], // make room for the arrows outside the box
        helpers: {
            overlay: {
                css: {
                    'background': 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.10)' // background semi-transparent
                }
            }
        }
    });
});
```

and the css to place the arrows outside the box and visible

```
.fancybox-nav {
    width: 60px;
}
.fancybox-nav span {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 0.5;
}
.fancybox-nav:hover span {
    opacity: 1;
}
.fancybox-next {
    right: -60px;
}
.fancybox-prev {
    left: -60px;
}
```

See **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/HdN8n/)**